# Update a screen on a webbrowser using applescript

Tags: applescript

Using safari on this website I can get applescript to change the input values for R G and B but I cannot Applescript to update the screen to reflect the new color.  The screen only changes when you tab out of the box.

```
tell text field 1 of group 1 of group 4 of group 4 of UI element 1 of scroll 
area 1 of group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "RGB 
Color Codes Chart"
    set value to item i of red1
end tell
```

The above code changes the value in safari of that cell but I cannot get Safari to update its screen.

Comment: Consider to use `do JavaScript`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Safari can execute javascript on a website. In most cases it's more reliable than GUI scripting.